# How do I inherit variables from specific instance of a superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, state, instance-variables

If I create several instances of a superclass, where their state is set to arbitrary values by the class constructor, how can I make sure a subclass inherits its state from a specific instance of the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the instance variables are "public", "package", "protected" or have no such modifier--if they are "private" the subclass would need getter and setter methods to access them.
2. Create an instance of the subclass when you are working with the superclass, rather than the superclass directly.  The subclass will inherit these state values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using instances. You can do this by creating subclasses of your superclass (instead of instances) using the arbitrary values in the constructor and then create subclasses of *those* subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the subclass has its own instance of its superclass. So:

```
public class Super
{
    protected int x;
    public Super( int x ) { this.x = x; }
}

public class Sub
{
    public Sub( int x ) { super( x ); }
    public void func() { System.out.println( x ); }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Sub a, b;
        a = new Sub( 1 );
        b = new Sub( 2 );
        a.func(); b.func();
    }
}
```

This will output

```
1
2
```